# Python: Attribute error and findAll

Tags: python

I'm using python 2.7 and I'm trying to web scrape a website that includes tables. I keep getting this error message: 
AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'findAll'

Am I using "findAll" incorrectly? Thanks!

```
wind = urllib2.urlopen('http://w1.weather.gov/data/obhistory/KCQX.html')
# print(third_page)
tables = wind.findAll('table')
data_table = tables[3]
rows = data_table.findAll('tr')
output_matrix = []
for row in rows:
    subrow = row.findAll('td')
    new_row = []
    if(len(subrow)>0):
        temp_row = []
        for subsubrow in subrow:
            temp_row.append(subsubrow.get_text().strip())
        output_matrix.append(temp_row)
```

Comment: Are you trying to use BeautifulSoup or from where do expect those `findAll` methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `wind` variable is a file-like object, it doesn't contain `findAll` methods. If you want to BeautifulSoup you need to create a new "soup" from the page contents:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

html = urllib2.urlopen('http://w1.weather.gov/data/obhistory/KCQX.html').read()
wind = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

The `BeautifulSoup`'s constructor can also take a file-like object, so you can drop the last `.read()`:

```
html = urllib2.urlopen('http://w1.weather.gov/data/obhistory/KCQX.html')
wind = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Comment: Thank you!! That makes sense.